# Selective USB UMS-Mode

Tags: android

is there a way to regulate the UMS-mode? I would like to implement a feature, that lets the user select which files he wants to share with a pc. Say you only want the pc see the picture subfolder, but not all the other folders on your sd. I am not sure if this is possible and most likely I will require root access when possible.

I know this will bring no real security, because you can always remove the sd card and read all the files on it. I thought of this feature mainly because of my crappy car radio. It can read mp3 files from a usb stick. But the many different folders and strange files on a android sd card seems to kill it. Furthermore I think there are a lot of other situation when you would prefer only to show a smaller part of your sd memory to a pc.

Can you imagine any other way to simulate the described behaviour? Can I generate completely new usb modes and implement my own UMS?

Every idea is welcome.

Sincerely Erik

Comment: And if someone removes the card from the phone and uses a card reader to bypass the security? Physical access is implied by USB = no security at all. May I ask why you want this please: and add this to the question for clarity of purpose? I'd be miffed if some app on *my* phone tried to limit access to *my* card when I browse with *my* PC.

Comment: I am not trying to improve security. This would be rather pointless, as you already mentioned. But I think such a feature woudl have multiple possible applications. One would by my crappy car radio. It can read mp3 files from USB sticks, but gets confused by the filenames used inside an android sd card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to regulate the UMS-mode?

Not from an SDK application. Also, bear in mind that UMS mode is being deprecated in favor of MTP.

> I am not sure if this is possible and most likely I will require root access when possible.

No, you will need to write your own custom firmware.

> Can I generate completely new usb modes and implement my own UMS?

By writing your own firmware, presumably, yes.

Comment: Well, thanks you for your answer. It seems it is as impossible to control by an app, as I have feared. I hoped for some less documented API options to configure the UMS mode.